# The right way to make a custom UITabBar inside UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to create an app with UITabBarController, in order to use Cocoa's own memory and view controllers management for switching between different view controllers.

However I do need to make a very custom UITabBar, which after much Googling I found out is not possible. Several things are not possible with original UITabBar:

- changing position and size of the TabBar,
- adding custom (non-tab) elements to the toolbar, such as search/dropdown

Is there any "legal" method of completely changing the design/subviews of TabBar but in the same time making use of UITabBarController and still getting app approved by Apple?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not much can be customized in tabbar but there are some good examples :-

1. [Custom Tabbar by iDevRecipes](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBar)
2. [Custom TabBar by brianCollins](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController)

It might not be exactly what you need but will give you direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I researched both solutions before asking this question. Both seem to have few serious issues and no bugfixes lately (last changes more than 6 months ago). I do understand that there is always possibility to use external library or code the solution on my own, but I am looking for clean solution, if there is any :)

Answer (score 1):

About changing the size you can extend UITabBar and overwrite the function sizeThatFits.
I'm sorry for not having an answer for the other points.

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize auxSize = size;
    auxSize.height = 54; // Put here the new height you want
    return auxSize;
}
```

I will tell you as soon as I will discover it.